# When the mean of a non-negative, integer-valued random variable goes to zero, does this imply anything about the other raw moments?

Tags: probability, random-graphs

When the mean of a non-negative, integer-valued random variable $X_n$, for example counting paths in a random graph on $n$ vertices between two fixed vertices, goes to zero,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n] =0$$

can we have $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n^3] = \infty$, or under what conditions does this occur? This seems reasonable given we just need two different sequences to have different limits, but a bit counter-intuitive, since we're counting objects, and the raw moments give the typical number of ordered pairs, triples, etc.

Comment: The addition of "under what conditions is it possible" changes the question quite a lot! :) I'll add a note here that my answer was intended only for the original version of the question which asked whether it was possible.

Comment: A simple, crystal clear example, is $P(X_n = n^2) = 1/n$ while $P(X_n = -n/(1 - 1/n)) = 1-1/n,$ then $E(X_n) = 0.$ However, $E(X_n^3) = n^5 -n^3/(1-1/n)^2 \to \infty.$ The conditions are that $X_n$ can have large values with small probability and small negative values with large probability, so that the mean cancells out, the assymetry of $X_n$ forces the third moment to be non-zero.

Comment: @WilliamM. A good example, though the original question called for a nonnegative variable that does this, which is $\epsilon$ more difficult. I've borrowed the idea to repair my broken answer. I've made my answer a community wiki since it stole your idea wholesale. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Start with an example that has a finite first moment and an infinite third moment, such as $X$ with probability function proportional to $\frac{1}{x^3}$ for $x \geq 1$. Then, modify it just a bit: let $X_n$ have probability function proportional to $\frac{1}{x^3 \log(x)^n}$ (let's say, restrict to $x \geq 3$ so we can guarantee $\log(x) > 1$).

The first moment will tend to zero, as $\sum_{x=3}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^3 \log(x)^n} < \frac{1}{\log(3)^n} \frac{\pi^2}{6} \to 0$, but the third moment will never exist, as $\sum_{x=3}^{\infty} \frac{x^3}{x^3\log(x)^n}$ diverges.

You can also adjust the moment at which this occurs by changing the power on $x$ in the denominator; changing it from $3$ to $5$ will guarantee existence of the third moment but not the fourth, for instance.

---

**EDIT:** I'd like to thank **A rural reader** for pointing out a flaw in my argument: by sweeping the normalization constant under the rug, I think my sequence doesn't actually do what it's supposed to do, because that normalization constant grows with $n$, and I believe it may do so fast enough to prevent $\mathbb E[X_n] \to 0$. Instead, let me choose a much simpler example that's more in the spirit of **William M**'s comment:

Let $X_n$ have the following distribution:
$$X_n = \begin{cases} n^2, & \text{w/ prob. } \frac{1}{n^3} \\ 0, & \text{w/ prob. } 1 - \frac{1}{n^3} \end{cases}.$$
Then $\mathbb E[X_n] = \frac{1}{n}$, while $\mathbb E[X_n^3] = n^2$.

Comment: This is obviously a genetically-engineered counterexample, and I don't claim that it arises naturally in graphs or counting or anything like that.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, we just need the sequences which give the expectations to have different limits. $P(X=0)$ goes to zero in both cases, but the sums $\mathbb{E}[X]=P(X=1)+2(P(X=2))+\dots$ and $\mathbb{E}[X^3]=P(X=1)+8(P(X=2))+\dots $have different limits.

Comment: Sure! Hopefully this helps illuminate the only important answer to your question: it all comes down to the specific convergence rate of $p(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: For completeness you might consider showing the normalization constant $C_n$ associated with $p_x = C_n x^{-3}\log^{-n}x$ grows sufficiently slowly as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Aruralreader Ooh, that's a great point -- I don't think it does. I think my example is broken. Thank you for pointing it out! I'll see if I can repair it.

Comment: This example is pretty nice, all higher moments tend to infinity as $E(X_n^p) = n^{2p-3}\to \infty$ ($n \to\infty$) as soon as $p > \frac{3}{2}.$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a concrete example about counting things in random graphs.

Let $H$ be the [$5$-vertex graph obtained by adding an edge to $K_4$](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=420):

[image]

Suppose that $X_n$ counts the number of copies of $H$ in $G_{n,p}$, for some carefully chosen $p$. Then $\mathbb E[X_n] = \Theta(n^5 p^7)$. So if we choose $p = o(n^{-5/7})$, then $\mathbb E[X_n] \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

However, for such values of $p$, we have $\mathbb E[X_n^2] = \Theta(n^6 p^8)$: $X_n^2$ counts ordered pairs of copies of $H$, and the $\Theta(n^6 p^8)$ term comes from two copies that share $K_4$ but have different edges coming out of the $K_4$. Whenever $p$ is (asymptotically) between $n^{-3/4}$ and $n^{-5/7}$, such as $p = n^{-0.74}$, we have $\mathbb E[X_n] \to 0$ but $\mathbb E[X_n^2] \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Similarly, there is a $\Theta(n^7 p^9)$ contribution to $\mathbb E[X_n^3]$ that comes from *three* copies of $H$ that all share the same $K_4$. So if we take a value of $p$ such as $n^{-0.77}$, then we get $\mathbb E[X_n] \to 0$, $\mathbb E[X_n^2] \to 0$, and $\mathbb E[X_n] \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Essentially, when you see a situation where the mean goes to $0$ but higher moments go to infinity, this tells you that $X_n$ counts objects that rarely appear, but appear in bunches when they do. That's what we see here: it is rare to find a copy of $H$ in $G_{n,p}$ for this range of $p$, but if you find one copy, you find many copies.

Comment: Is there a way to assert whether the the probability $P(X_n=0) \to 0$, even though things like $\text{Var}(X_n)/(\mathbb{E}(X_{n}))^{2} \to \infty$? Would one expect that $P(X_n=0)$ may well not go to zero in this situation where the instances occur rarely, but in bunches when they do? The mean can go to infinity now, its just all the moments grow fast with $n$.

Comment: There are higher-moment methods analogous to the second-moment method, but I think the better answer in such cases is "understand what is causing the correlation between the objects you're counting, and take it into account". In the graph-counting example I gave, we'd want to count the number of copies of $K_4$, instead. A famous analysis-of-variance result in combinatorics was done by Wormald for showing that $P(X_n = 0) \to 0$ when $X_n$ is the number of Hamiltonian cycles in a random $d$-regular graph. (Here, the "explanation" for correlation was finding small cycles in the graph!)

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathbb{E}(X_n)\to0 $ then it is totally possible for $\mathbb{E}\left(X_n^3\right)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. The $X_n$'s may have finite mean but their third moments may be infinite, for example. In such a case, the limit of the third moments will be infinity (aka does not exist).

Even in the case that $X_n$'s are random variables supported on a finite set, $\mathbb{E}(X_n)\to 0$ does not imply convergence to zero of any higher moments.